# Design: Mandatory reference to one side of a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: database, database-design

Apologies if the title isn't clear but I don't know how to sum up this issue clearly in one sentence (am new to relational dbs).

I've got the following many-to-many relationship: each contact has to consist of 1 person and 1 company.

What I can't grasp is how I make it mandatory that a company has at least one contact. Do I just need to make the contact table have a primary rather than composite key, and then reference that from the companies table, making it not null? But don't I then have the circular problem of needing a company to create a contact and also a contact to create a company?

[image: ERD]

I'm using Sequelize, but happy to have answers just using SQL and I'll work it out, would just appreciate some direction

```
Person.belongsToMany(Company, { through: Contact });
Company.belongsToMany(Person, { through: Contact });

personOne.addCompany(companyOne, { through: { position: 'jobtitle' } });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stored procedure that encapsulates the insert into the three tables.

Pseudocode:

```
procedure insert_contact (Person p, Company c, position pos)
begin tran
    if (p not exists in People) insert into People (p);
    if (c not exists in Companies) insert into Companies (c);
    insert into contact (p, c, pos);
commit tran
```

Then, you have to remove the permission to insert into People and Companies tables directly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot